# Create DataTable using fetch api

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to create a [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) using the fetch API.

So i am using the following [API](https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/3-18-2020)

I am basically trying to get all the stats for USA so i did the following.

```
const getNewCases = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/3-18-2020');
  const data = await response.json();
  let usa = data.filter(val => {
  return val.countryRegion === 'US';
});
  console.log(usa)
};
```

So at this point i am wondering if it is possible to create a DataTable using this result. All the examples i saw on Datatables are using JQuery and making some ajax call. I would love some guidance on how to make a datatable without JQuery.

I am very new to JS so please forgive if it is a bad question. I am just trying to learn this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/34nckva6/

Comment: @shrys can you please post this as an answer so i can accept it and others may benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the DataTable as follows for the data that's coming from the API:

You can use the following option to disable the `Show Entries` dropdown:

```js
bLengthChange: false
```

```js
const getNewCases = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/3-18-2020');
  const data = await response.json();
  let usa = data.filter(val => {
    return val.countryRegion === 'US';
  });
  $('#loadingLabel').hide();
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    data: usa,
    bLengthChange: false,
    columns: [
      { data: 'provinceState', title: 'State' },
      { data: 'countryRegion', title: 'Country' },
      { data: 'lastUpdate', title: 'Last Update' },
      { data: 'confirmed', title: 'Confirmed' },
      { data: 'deaths', title: 'Deaths' },
      { data: 'recovered', title: 'Recovered' }
    ]
  });
};

scrollToPager = () => {
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: y + $('#myTable').height()
  })
}

getNewCases();
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="scrollToPager()">Scroll Down</button>
<table id="myTable"></table>
<div id="loadingLabel">Loading...</div>
```

To load all rows:

```js
bPaginate: false
```

```js
const getNewCases = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/daily/3-18-2020');
  const data = await response.json();
  let usa = data.filter(val => {
    return val.countryRegion === 'US';
  });
  $('#loadingLabel').hide();
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    data: usa,
    bPaginate: false,
    columns: [
      { data: 'provinceState', title: 'State' },
      { data: 'countryRegion', title: 'Country' },
      { data: 'lastUpdate', title: 'Last Update' },
      { data: 'confirmed', title: 'Confirmed' },
      { data: 'deaths', title: 'Deaths' },
      { data: 'recovered', title: 'Recovered' }
    ]
  });
};

scrollToPager = () => {
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: y + $('#myTable').height()
  })
}

getNewCases();
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="scrollToPager()">Scroll Down</button>
<table id="myTable"></table>
<div id="loadingLabel">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: minor question - do you know how we can get rid of the "show 10 entries" and instead have a option to let people scroll down? not sure if that is possible

Comment: Also if it is possible to rename the columns too rather than using default name from the api?

Comment: @Dinero i've updated the answer, did not include latitude longitude related data as I don't think it would be relevant to show

Comment: yeah that is perfect and by entries i meant i would wanna load all the rows rather than just showing 10 entries. I am guessing that is a pageLength option or something?

Comment: @Dinero yes you can use `bPaginate` option and set it to false

Comment: yes you could set [dynamic scroll height](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_dynamic.html) to your datatable

Comment: yeah super i think this is all i needed and last question is it possible to change color of table i am guessing there is custom css somewhere i can use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209923/discussion-between-shrys-and-dinero).